# POSIX, Unix, Linux and Minix: What is what?

Tags: linux, posix, minix

I am confused by the many related terms in the topic "UNIX".
How are the terms *POSIX*, *UNIX*, *Linux* and *Minix* related?
Which one is the root of all etc...?

Answer (score 2):

See wikipedia.

[POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) is a *specification* (written on papers, or in many web pages, notably [OpenGroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX)).

[Unix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix) is a family of [operating systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system), originally started at Bell Labs (by Thompson, Ritchie, Kernighan et al..). Later, Unix inspired POSIX. Read the [history of Unix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Unix).

[Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux) is a free software kernel under GPLv2 license started by Linus Torvarlds (mixed with [GNU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU) applications, hence called GNU/Linux; Linus originally used [Minix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system), a Unix-like system by Tanenbaum et al, but was unhappy and coded the first [Linux kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel)). Linux is (nearly, and quite) POSIX compliant, and quite inspired by Unix. Read also about the [History of Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Linux).

Actually, you'll use an entire [Linux distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution).